# ESP-01 OTA Error uploading

Tags: esp8266, ota

Im trying to do OTA upload from Arduino IDE.

Uploaded BasicOTA to ESP-01 with flash size set to (FS:2mb, OTA 1019kb).
ESP-01 connects and shows up in Port selection, but when trying to upload I get

```
Uploading.................................................

14:40:35 [ERROR]: Error Uploading
```

Thats the only output I get.
Anyone had similar issue?

Thx

Comment: Does your ESP-01 *have* that much flash?

Comment: nop, read wrong the chip info value. It said 4Mbit and I read 4mb. Dumb me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ESP-01 comes in two variants: blue, with 512KiB flash, and black, with 1MiB flash.

You have chosen an arrangement that needs 4MiB flash.  It won't fit.

Choose a suitable flash size for your board.

Comment: Im using Blue variant. Read the chip info using espressifs flash tool and it read 4MBit. In my haste I read 4MB not Mbit :) I have a black variant, will try with it